# How is it legitimate to use require in Electron's client when no there is no explicit import of any require framework?

Tags: javascript, browser, electron, require

To communicate with the main process in Electron, the renderer process requires the `ipcMain` module ( https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md ):

```
<script>
  // In renderer process (web page).
  const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
</script>
```

I'm puzzled as to why this is legitimate. In the client html file which contains this script there is no reference to any require framework ( there is no script tag to import any require framework ). Yet out of thin air you can use require, which is not a Javascript keyword.

How does the require mechanism work in Electron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron's renderer process *is not* plain chromium process - when Electron launches renderer window, it internally inject global object enables Electron specific features. `require` is one of them, patching global to expose node.js module resolution in chromium process.